# How to create a new virtual network adapter in windows 8?

Tags: adapter, vpn

I have tried to install Packetix VPN client on windows 8 (64-bit). It cannot create a network adapter on my system. I tried to make a network adapter manually but i cant seem to find the option to create on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Command Prompt(Admin) in Windows 8 to setup a virtual network adapter:
            use following commands:

```
        netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=mynetwork key=12345678 mode=allow keyusage=persistent

            // and when you press enter,there will be three messages in command prompt
           //after that you can start your virtual network
      netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

This works for me